# Steve will only move backwards on Xbox 360

Tags: technical-issues, minecraft-legacy-console

When I run the game he starts walking backwards.  I can move him in any direction other than fowards. I changers the camera view to see if there was abnormal, but he is fine in crouch or standing.

Comment: Did you try restarting the console? If you did and it still doesn't work, could there be a problem with the controller?

Comment: Check your controller configuration. Some controller configurations reverse the movement (i.e. push forward to go back, push backward to go forward). Also, try a different controller and see if that has any effect

Answer (score 2):

**It is a common bug, but the fix is easy.**

When Steve moves backwards without your control, you can just press your down button, and it will be fixed.

At least, it is, for me.

Comment: D-pad Down button?  Or push in on the stick?

Comment: I don't own a Xbox 360, but I think it is the stick.

Answer (score 0):

Use a different controller and try it. If the problem keeps happening then it is a Minecraft bug. If not then your controller is glitchy.